# Modernizr fails to detect scrollbar stylability

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, modernizr, feature-detection

I'm using Modernizr to choose to hide all scrollbars when a page is being viewed in firefox. This is because I've styled the scrollbars using webkit's ::-webkit-scrollbar selectors and haven't found a suitable alternative for firefox.

Since it's best practice to keep from using the User Agent String, I'm following the most common recommendation to use Modernizr for feature detection instead of browser detection.

I'm using the CSS Stylable Scrollbars property (cssscrollbar). That's supposed to return true for everything except firefox, but instead returns false for all browsers for me. (including Chrome and Safari, for which we have the scrollbars styled and working).

Other than including the custom-modernizr.js file in the header of the site and using it in javascript I'm not sure what other code is worth sharing, but I've got to be choosy with the code I share because it's for work.

Here's the bit where I check:

```
if (Modernizr.cssscrollbar) {
      console.log("Browser has css scrollbars!"); // This never gets run in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari.
    } else {
      console.log("Browser does not have css scrollbars.");
    }
```

Any ideas to fix Modernizr, or another way to determine when to remove the scrollbars?